# Test a condition in a while loop then exit while loop in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to understand how to nest an if statement inside a for loop and have it exit the for loop once the if statement is executed. I have an array, the for loop goes through the array to see if an ID exists, if it does its supposed to delete it, if it doesn't exist then it should print an error message. What is happening is the condition is test in the nested if statement in the while loop and printing the error message 3 times. I would like it to only print the error message once.

In my main method I have

```
remove("3");
remove("3");
```

on the first one it should just remove that ID and print that it was rem, the second one it should only print the error message once. This is a project for school and requires no input from a user. I'm just trying to understand how to make this work without printing out repeat error messages

```
public static void remove(String studentID) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < thestudents.size(); i++) 
    {

        Student temp = thestudents.get(i);

        if (temp.getStudentID()==(Integer.parseInt(studentID))) 
        {
            thestudents.remove(i);
            System.out.println("Student " + temp.getFirstName() + " was removed");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Student with ID " + studentID + " Was not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
Student with ID 3 Was not found!
Student with ID 3 Was not found!
Student Jack was removed
Student with ID 3 Was not found!
Student with ID 3 Was not found!
Student with ID 3 Was not found!
Student with ID 3 Was not found!
Student with ID 3 Was not found!
```

Expectation:

```
Student Jack was removed
Student with ID 3 Was not found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding a *break* will remove the output after the match, but the output before the match will remain.

I guess you want to get rid of all of the *false negative* outputs.

Therefore you have to move the negative output (which is the content of the `else` block) after the loop (deleting the `else` line) and make sure this code gets not executed when the ID was found.

The best way to do this is to add a `return` as the last statement in the `if` block.

```
for (int i = 0; i < thestudents.size(); i++) 
{
    Student temp = thestudents.get(i);
    if (temp.getStudentID()==(Integer.parseInt(studentID))) 
    {
        thestudents.remove(i);
        System.out.println("Student " + temp.getFirstName() + " was removed");
        return; // leaving the method whe ID found
    }
}
// is only executed when ID not found
System.out.println("Student with ID " + studentID + " Was not found!)";
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I used the return earlier but didn't move the error message to be outside of the loop. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `break` inside the `if` statement. If that `if` statement is `true`, then the loop will terminate.

```
if (temp.getStudentID()==(Integer.parseInt(studentID))) {
    hestudents.remove(i);
    System.out.println("Student " + temp.getFirstName() + " was removed");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Exactly! break would be a better choice over return;

Comment: _break would be a better choice over return_ No, it is not! a `break` requires additional logic after the loop to find out if the loop was completed without hit or left early with hit.  this additional logic is not required wit a `return`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `break` statement to terminate the loop, or better yet, a `return` statement to completely terminate the method once you find the appropriate item:

```
public static void remove(String studentID) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < thestudents.size(); i++) 
    {

        Student temp = thestudents.get(i);

        if (temp.getStudentID()==(Integer.parseInt(studentID))) 
        {
            thestudents.remove(i);
            System.out.println("Student " + temp.getFirstName() + " was removed");
            return;
        }
    }

    // If we get here it means we haven't returned, so the student wasn't found
    System.out.println("Student with ID " + studentID + " Was not found!");
}
```

Comment: Well the return will stop the execution, but, it will also terminate the method. So the last statement will not print anything. Also, if it would have been an int type method, then, you can not simply right 'return;'

Comment: @RishabhKumar We **want** the last statement to not print, as the student was indeed found. If it weren't a `void` method, you'd just return a value.